# AWS RDS changing password automatic every 2 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have seen this problem in others Post, but there was not any solution for this.
I have a public RDS database, and every 2 days, my credentials does not work anymore and I have to set a new password to connect it again.
Could anyone give me some explanation about this?
I have any process running changing the database at all, this SUPER strange, and the other people asking the same could not have any solution at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you have this configured? [Rotate Amazon RDS database credentials automatically with AWS Secrets Manager | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/)

Comment: No at all ,I never did that. I am relative new to AWS RDS (1 Year experience),and this is the first time creating a RDS database, super simple to create, super simple to communicate with, but honestly, this behavior it s driving me crazy. The other people complaining about the same, we share 1 thing in common. Al Db Engines are PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you resetting the Master Password when you need to get back in? If so, I'd recommend looking at the AWS CloudTrail logs to see whether there have been any API calls to AWS to Modify the database and update the password. Otherwise, it would be an internal call inside PostgreSQL, in which case you could check the [PostgreSQL database log files - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try all that.